# Is this sequence always periodic?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

The sequence $a_1,a_2,\dots$ contains only positive reals. Suppose that for any $i$ positive integer
$$n-(a_i+a_{i+1})+\dfrac{a_ia_{i+1}-a_{i+2}+1}{n}=1$$ 
where $n$ is a fixed positive real.

Is it always true that the sequence $a_i$ is periodic? This problem is from Rookie Team Contest MOP 2001. I need your help!

Comment: Try $n=1$, so then $a_{i+2} = 1-(a_i-a_{i+1}) + a_ia_{i+1}$ and it looks like if initialized properly the $a_i$ sequence will always increase.

Comment: As Michael commented, for $n=1$, we have $a_{i+2}=(a_{i+1}-1)(a_i-1)$. So, we see that $a_i$ is increasing for $a_1=a_2=3$, for example.

Comment: But what if $n\neq 1$. I mean in the problem we don’t know $n$, we only know that it is a fixed positive real and satisfy the equation!

Answer (score 0):

By multiplying both sides in $n$ we have $$n^2-n(a_i+a_{i+1})+a_ia_{i+1}-a_{i+2}+1=n$$therefore $$a_{i+2}=(a_i-n)(a_{i+1}-n)-n+1$$defining $b_i=a_i-n$ we have $$b_{i+2}=b_ib_{i+1}-2n+1$$therefore $b_i$ is periodic if and only if $a_i$ is periodic. Now choose $n={1\over 2}$ therefore $$b_{i+2}=b_{i+1}b_i$$ where for $b_1=2$ and $b_2=2$ we have$${b_3=2^2\\b_4=2^3\\b_5=2^5\\b_6=2^8\\b_7=2^{11}\\\vdots}$$therefore $$\Large b_i=2^{f_i}$$ where $f_i$ is the famous Fibonacci sequence. Since $f_i$ grows unbounded, so do $b_i$ and $a_i$ which implies on non-periodicity of $a_i$.